# How to remove a space in XML using stylesheet using RegEx

Tags: regex, xml, xslt

I have an XML and I am looking for finding particular tag (in this case "FirstName") and removing space in the value only if there is a - character before the space.

In other words, I want to keep spaces if there is no - front of them. I want to do this using an XSL stylesheet with RegEx matching and replace function.

Expected result is Sam-Louise, removing space between "Sam-" and "Louise"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NCV Version="1.14">
    <Invoice>
        <customer>
            <customerId>12785</customerId>
            <FirstName>Sam- Louise</FirstName>
            <LastName>Jones</LastName>
        </customer>
    </Invoice>
</NCV>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following RegEx in match

```
(\<FirstName\>.*?-)\s+
```

And replace it with the first captured group `$1`

RegEx [`(\<FirstName\>.*?-)\s+`](https://regex101.com/r/bQ4pD1/2) matches,

1. `\<FirstName\>.*?-`: Literal `<FirstName>` followed by any character non-greedy, until first hyphen is found. This match is added in the captured group.
2. `\s+`: Match one or more of the space characters.

By replacing it with `$1`, will remove the spaces after hyphen.

Comment: Thanks @Tushar, characters < and > need to be escaped in stylesheet

Answer (score 1):

**This is one possible XSLT :**

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="FirstName">
        <FirstName>
            <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '-\s+', '-')"/>
        </FirstName>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

**<kbd>[`xsltransform.net demo`](http://xsltransform.net/6r5Gh3z)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
<NCV Version="1.14">
   <Invoice>
      <customer>
         <customerId>12785</customerId>
         <FirstName>Sam-Louise</FirstName>
         <LastName>Jones</LastName>
      </customer>
   </Invoice>
</NCV>
```